# Bash Script - Need to remove files from a directory till the Directory size is Less than 8 TB

Tags: linux, bash, awk, do-while, du

Below is the high level scenario for which I need to create a bash script.

- A directory on the server **`- /sasdata2/SAS-USERS/PBU/`**
- The size of the above directory should not be more than 8 TB
- If the size exceeds 8 TB, need to delete the oldest files by 'created/modified' date to get the size back down to 8 TB.
- Several sub-directories in this main directory but nothing should be removed from the sub-directories. Only files in the main directory can be removed.

Below is a script I am using, but it is going in an infinite loop on the while statement. Need your help in making a script for the above scenario.

```
while [ "$(du -shb /sasdata2/SAS-USERS/PBU | awk '{print $1}')" -gt 900 ]
do
  find /sasdata2/SAS-USERS/PBU -maxdepth 0 -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\n' | \
  sort -n | head -n 25 | cut -d $'\t' -f 2-  | xargs -d '\n' rm -f
done
```

Comment: If the subdirectories we are not allowed to touch are larger than 8 TB, there is no way for the loop to finish.

Comment: Why does it need to be Bash?  As opposed to, say, Perl or Python?

Comment: Have you thought about maybe compressing some of your users' files rather than arbitrarily deleting them? Btw, as the path to your poor SAS users' files appears more than once in your script, you should consider putting it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think your while condition is wrong. du -b will give you bytes, why comparing to 900?

Beside, Why do you need a loop on du and delete arbitrary 25 files? calculate with du how many bytes you are over 8TB, then ls -ltr and in a loop delete files and sum their size until you reach the over bytes

Comment: Hi Eran, I was testing it on a folder and deleting files greater than 900 bytes. I will try this approach and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help.